# PHPSESSID security issues?

Tags: php, security, session

I've been curious for a while now about the security issues surrounding the PHP session name: `PHPSESSID`.

I've noticed that some websites rename their session ID cookie, while others just leave it as the default.

Is there any security advantage in using a different name? or is it merely useful for being able to track multiple sessions per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sometimes to change the default sessionID if you are uber-worried about session hijacking though the chances of someone successfully hijacking a session are pretty well slim if you take the most rudimentary steps in sanitizing your data, turn off register globals and only accept the specific POST or GET variables cast correctly from your forms...

you can read about [Session Fixation here](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-fixation) (which is what the changing of the standard sessionId is usually used to combat)..

Comment: -1 changing the session name does not defend against session fixation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to obscure the fact that you are running php then you should change the name.  However what is more common is that developers get the horrible idea of reinventing the wheal and writing their own (very broken) session handler.  9 times out of 10 this approach is far less secure than your usual `session_start()`.

Comment: Of course, some people get paranoid about exposing PHP via the session cookie name, then completely forget/neglect the X-Powered-By header and ServerTokens stuff in Apache.

Comment: @Marc B and forget setting `expose_php = Off` in their php.ini :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make the slightest bit of difference.

Answer (score 2):

No, the session ID’s name is just a name to identify the session ID; you can change it to whatever you want as long as your system knows that name.

But as already mentioned, you might want to change the name to obscure your system. But there are also other aspects that can be used to identify you system besides the session ID’s name.